# I want to select column from a Excel sheet which has multi word coloumn name using oleDB select command?

Tags: c#, oledb, oledbdataadapter

This is my code

```
OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand();
OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter();
DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
cmdExcel.CommandText = SELECT Name,EmailID,PhoneNumber  From [Sheet1$]
oda.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
oda.Fill(dtable);
```

This one working fine but

SELECT Name,EmailID,Phone Number  From [Sheet1$]  ... not working

I'm trying with SELECT "Name","EmailID","Phone Number"  From [Sheet1$]  but not working properly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
  cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT Name,EmailID,PhoneNumber AS [Phone Number]  
  FROM [Sheet1$]";
```

OR

```
   cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT Name,EmailID,[Phone Number] AS PhoneNumber  
   FROM [Sheet1$]";
```